# C# Regex return numbers in brakets

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this:

```
numbers(23,54)
```

The input format is like this:

```
numbers([integer1],[integer2])
```

How can I get the number "23" and "54" using regular expression ? Or are there any other better ways to get?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid regular expressions usage thus your input has consistent format:

```
string input = "numbers(23,54)";
var numbers = input.Replace("numbers(", "")
                   .Replace(")", "")
                   .Split(',')
                   .Select(s => Int32.Parse(s));
```

Or even (if you don't afraid of magic numbers):

```
input.Substring(8, input.Length - 9).Split(',').Select(s => Int32.Parse(s))
```

UPDATE Here also Regex version

```
var numbers = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+")
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(m => Int32.Parse(m.Value));
```

Comment: On the other hand, regular expressions can be used to ensure your input is correct (rather than, say, `25numbers(numbers()42,1numbers(3`) and, in this case, can probably be more efficient too.

Comment: @Rawling agree with you, but if format is consistent (as stated in question) this will go :)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah Use (\d+) to get the numbers correctly
This is the correct way